# How to toggle a modal with Javascript/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to trigger a modal popup with a PHP function. So far, I have gotten to this point:

PHP / Javascript code being injected:

```
<?php
if($show_modal == true) {
   echo "<script>";
   echo "$('#myModal').modal('show');";
   echo "</script>";
} 
?>
```

PHP Function:

```
<?php
if($show_modal == true) {
   echo "<script>";
   echo "$('#myModal').modal('show');";
   echo "</script>";
} 
?>
```

the code is being properly injected on the site, as it will execute a test alert script, and the javascript used in that function when triggered by a button, functions perfectly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: PHP is server side, it has nothing to do with whether your modal is open or not on the client side.

Comment: PHP, running on the server-side, runs only once before the page is sent to the browser. JavaScript, running on the client-side, run after the page is opened in browser. Therefore the php cannot control or do anything in page on user's action unless you send the event pack and redraw/reload the page or section of page via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You should check where you are placing that code, It could be that your script is placed before the element has been loaded by the DOM.

So, if the resultant html is:

```
<script>
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
</script>
<body>
   <div id="myModal"></div>
<body>
```

It may not work because you're trying to show a nonexistent object. So you should place it after the div element or use the document ready event.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
   });
</script>
<body>
   <div id="myModal"></div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not a function.  A function would be done like this:

```
function showmodal() {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "$('#myModal').modal('show');";
    echo "</script>";
}

if($show_modal == true) {
    showmodal();
}
```

PHP will run once.  If you want something to happen in realtime though (a typical popup) - you may want to consider writing your code differently - using Javascript probably.  To give you a really good answer, it would be helpful if you could provide more information.  What is the $show_modal variable?  What condition causes it to be "true" or "false"?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function with toggle.

```
if($show_modal == true) {
showmodal();
}

function showmodal() {
echo "<script>";
echo "$('#myModal').modal('toggle');";
echo "</script>";
}
```